# Subspace of tangent feasible directions

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $h: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $h(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1^3 - x_2 + x_3^2, x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3)$

I define $V(x)$ as a subspace formed by all directions tangent to some constrained set at the point $x$.

i.e

$V(x) : = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \nabla h_i(x)^ty = 0, i = 1, ... , m\}$

How would I compute $V(0,0,0)$ and $V(-1,0,1)$ ?

$\nabla h_i(x) = \{\langle (3x_1^2,0,1),(-1,1,1),(2x_3,0,1) \rangle \} $

So then $V(0,0,0) = \{ (\langle (0,0,1),(-1,1,1),(0,0,1) \rangle \} $

is this correct?